# Displaying a changing loop of pictures in a dialog?

Tags: java, android

I'm not having much success doing this the way I thought would work so I'll ask the experts.

I have an ArrayList of ten URLs linking to images. I want to display the first URL for 2 seconds, then get the second URL and do the same until the end.

Here is what I have so far, I think perhaps I'm not going about it in the best way with a dialog in postExecute?:

```
 private class LiveView extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, ArrayList<String>> {
        ProgressDialog dialog;
        private volatile boolean running = true;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(
                        myView.this,
                        "Working",
                        "Info message . . .",
                        true,
                        true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){

                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                                cancel(true);                           
                            }
                        }
                );
            }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {
              running = false;
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(String... passed) {



            while (running) {

            //removed the code here that sends the request to to make this shorter the server but it works fine
            return responseFromServer.arrayListofURLs;           //list or URLs 

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> listURLs) {      
            dialog.cancel();

            Dialog liveView = new Dialog(myView.this, R.style.Dialog);
            liveView.setContentView(R.layout.liveview_dialogue);
            TextView title = (TextView)liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewTitle);           
            Button button = (Button) liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewButton);
            ImageView trackImage = (ImageView)liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewImage);

            //I want to loop through the ten images here? 

            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {

                }
            });
            liveView.show();



        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To finish the answer with some code, here is how I did it with a handler. I didn't need to pass any variables as I'd created the ListArray of bitmaps globally for the AsyncTask. I also used a boolean value to end the handler if the dialog was closed.

```
        liveView = new Dialog(myView.this, R.style.Dialog);
        liveView.setContentView(R.layout.liveview_dialogue);
        TextView title = (TextView)liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewTitle);           
        Button button = (Button) liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewButton);
        trackImage = (ImageView)liveView.findViewById(R.id.liveViewImage);





        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                run = false;
                liveView.dismiss();
            }
        });
        liveView.show();

        final Handler handler = new Handler(); 
        final Runnable r = new Runnable()
        {
            Iterator<Bitmap> it = images.iterator();
            public void run() 
            {   
                if(run){
                trackImage.setImageBitmap(it.next());
                if(it.hasNext())
                handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a handler, and send it a message with a 2 second delay via postDelayed.  Whenever you get the message, show the next image by calling trackImage.setImage.  When they eventually close the dialog, remove any pending messages from the handler.